# Roxy Fileman problems with umlauts

Tags: tinymce, roxy-fileman

i implemented the roxy fileman into my tinymce editor, it works wonderfull, but i have a little bit problems with uploading files with umlauts (ä,ö,ü,ß) and so on. how to handle this problem?

Comment: Modify your code to improve the behavior or give up and mark it as characteristics of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Search for upload.php in your fileman/php/ dir. You will find a foreach loop starting in line 37. Inside the loop you will find the following line (should be the first line in the loop):

```
$filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$k];
```

Insert the following code after this line:

```
// replace umlaute and white spaces
$filename = str_replace(' ', '-', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('ä'), 'ae', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('Ä'), 'Ae', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('ö'), 'oe', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('Ö'), 'Oe', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('ü'), 'ue', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('Ü'), 'Ue', $filename);
$filename = str_replace(utf8_decode('ß'), 'ss', $filename);
```

done.

If you want to make sure, the file name only consists of charachters that Roy Fileman can handle, you have to add the following line after the umlaute-conversion.

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]/', '-', $filename);
```

This remove all sorts of accents and special charachters without a replacement. If you want to convert more language specific characters (e.g. é, è, ê => e), you can add more str_replace lines.